# Inequality with $a\le b\le c$ and $a+b+c=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be positive reals with $a\le b\le c$ and $a+b+c=1$. Is it true that
$$
3a(b+c)+2bc \le 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\,\,?
$$

Comment: What did you try? What are your thoughts

Comment: Dear @Jaideep Khare. In this problem we work with polynomial with three variables.

Comment: @Michael Sir, I think the tag inequality is sufficient. I don't think we're using any concept purely from polynomials. If this question should be tagged under "polynomials", then there are tonnes of other posts too, which should have this tag.

Comment: I don't think so,  but if you say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)-(3ab+3ac+2bc)(a+b+c)=(b+c-2a)bc\geq0.$$

Answer (score 0):

we get $$3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)-3a(b+c)-2bc=3\,{a}^{2}b+3\,{a}^{2}c+3\,a{b}^{2}+6\,abc+3\,a{c}^{2}+3\,{b}^{2}c+3\,
b{c}^{2}-3\,ab-3\,ac-2\,bc
$$
abd with $$c=1-a-b$$ we obtain
$$b(3a-1)(a+b-1)$$
Can you proceed?